# Be a direct sum implies zero intersection

Tags: abstract-algebra, direct-sum

Let $M_1$ and $M_2$ be a submodule of $M$ and $M \cong M_1 \oplus M_2$ then $M_1 \cap M_2 = \{0\}$
can you please help.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: We write $M_1 \oplus M_2$ to denote the module $M_1+M_2$ when $M_1 \cap M_2=\{0_M\}$. So, as one of the previous comments suggests, it follows by definition of direct sum.

Comment: here $M_1 \oplus M_2$ means {($m_1$ ,$ n_1$):$m_1 \in M_1 $& $m_2 \in M_2$}

Comment: Okay @Kim. I'd suggest using $M_1 \times M_2$ instead of $M_1 \oplus M_2$ given your previous comment.

Answer (score 2):

The statement itself is false: it is entirely possible to have an isomorphism $g: M_1\oplus M_2\to M$ without having $M_1\cap M_2=0$. For instance, consider $M_1=M_2=M=\Bbb Z^{\Bbb N}$. If you are requiring that the map $s:M_1\oplus M_2\to M$, $s(x,y)=x+y$ is an isomorphism (in one way or another, this is what most authors refer to when they say that $M$ is the *internal* direct sum of $M_1$ and $M_2$), then $M_1\cap M_2=0$, because $(x,-x)\in \ker s$ for all $x\in M_1\cap M_2$.

Comment: So this map isn't isomorphic, I don't understand.

Comment: For s: $s(x,-x) = 0 = s(0,0)$ so there isn't injective and so isomorphism.

Comment: @Kim Observe that if $(x,-x)\in M_1 \oplus M_2$, then $x \in M_1 \cap M_2$.

Comment: @Hey Oh Yes so if we have isomorphism then $M_1 \cap M_2% = {0}$ and I don't understand your example. what is the isomorphism for $\mathbb{Z}^\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: @Kim I'll try to expand on the above answer. If $s$ is an isomorphism, then we have that $M_1 \cap M_2 = \{0_M\}$. I hope this is clear. This does not hold in general, that is, if you have an isomoprhism $g:M_1\oplus M_2 \rightarrow M$ in general, you need not have that $M_1\cap M_2=\{0_M\}$. To see this, set $M=M_1=M_2=\mathbb{Z}^\mathbb{N}$, considered as $\mathbb{Z}$-modules. Then, $\mathbb{Z}^{\mathbb{N}}\oplus \mathbb{Z}^{\mathbb{N}} \cong \mathbb{Z}^{\mathbb{N}}$ as groups. Hence, they are also isomorphic as $\mathbb{Z}$-modules. It is easy to see that $M_1 \cap M_2 \neq \{0_M\}$

Comment: @Hey Oh Maybe $M_1$ and $M_2$ are proper submodule for M.

Comment: See this https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2042668/direct-sum-of-modules-if-and-only-if-is-sum-without-intersection?rq=1. for the r=2.

Comment: @Kim Doesn't matter, you can even work with $M=\mathbb{Z}^{\mathbb{Z}}$. If you restrict yourself to maps of the type $s$, that is, if you assume that the map given by the "sum of components" is an isomorphism, then you have pairwise zero intersection in general. Loosely speaking, an isomorphism in general is too weak to imply zero intersection.